# GNURadio callback in python OOT module

Tags: python, callback, gnuradio

I'm trying to implement an OOT Python module in GNURadio 3.7 that should update a parameter (boolean) from the QT GUI while it is running. So far, I have included the callback function in the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<block>
  <name>Synchronous Frequency Sweep</name>
  <key>PLOP_sync_sweep</key>
  <category>[PLOP]</category>
  <import>import PLOP</import>
  <make>PLOP.sync_sweep($samp_rate, $sweep_range, $sweep_speed, $sweep_bool)</make>

  <callback>set_sweepBool($sweep_bool)</callback>

  <param>
    <name>Enable Sweep</name>
    <key>sweep_bool</key>
    <value>True</value>
    <type>bool</type>
    <option>
      <name>Enabled</name>
      <key>True</key>
    </option>
    <option>
      <name>Disabled</name>
      <key>False</key>
    </option>
  </param>
```

I also declared the callback function in the python file:

```
class sync_sweep(gr.sync_block):
    """
    docstring for block sync_sweep
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 samp_rate,
                 sweep_range,
                 sweep_speed,
                 sweep_bool):

        self.set_sweepBool(sweep_bool)

        gr.sync_block.__init__(self,
            name="sync_sweep",
            in_sig=None,
            out_sig=[numpy.float32])

        self.d_samp_rate = samp_rate
        self.d_sweep_range = sweep_range
        self.d_sweep_speed = sweep_speed
        self.d_sweep_bool = sweep_bool
```

And then I call it in the work function without success :(

```
def work(self, input_items, output_items):
    out = output_items[0]
    self.set_sweepBool(self.d_sweep_bool)
```

Any suggestions why the callback is not updating the boolean value when changing it from the QT GUI?

Thanks beforehand,

Joaquin.

Comment: Purely a guess - perhaps `set_sweepBool` is attached to the top block, while `self` refers to the instance of the `sync_sweep` block?